# How to make multiple HTTP REQUEST (data integration)

Tags: java, regex

So I have to use this link www.wook.pt/ to search various authors. So if you put a name of an author for example JK_Rowling it will appear like this www.wook.pt/product/facets?palavras=jk+rowling so i have to use this www.wook.pt/product/facets?palavras= so i can get the books of any author that appears in that first page. and i did the begining like this

```
String link = "http://www.wook.pt/product/facets?palavras=" + nome_escritor;
    ArrayList<obras> res = new ArrayList();
    String pesquisa =""; 
    HttpRequestFunctions.httpRequest(link,pesquisa,"ESCRITORES.txt");
```

but now i have to get information from the books that were shown in that page and the teacher told me that i had to make a new http request, but do i have to do that for every book cause they have diferent links? How do i do it?

Comment: Why not just iterate through a list of all the links?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to do something like:

```
links = parse html response
for each link in links:
   get that URL and parse the results
```

You can use something like [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to parse the HTML.  Find the pattern that the book links use and the use the links that match that pattern.